# How can Intel Microcode be installed manually in elementary OS?

Tags: software-installation, wifi

Installed elementary OS Juno on a Lenovo ideapad S130-11IGM (along with windows 10). WLAN can not be activated.

I would like to install Intel's microcode for my WLAN board manually (no other internet access).

The relevant microcode is available now dezipped on an USB drive as
`iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode` and `iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode`

How can a Linux beginner install that code in Elementary OS? Direct access to the directory `/lib/firmware` is blocked.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> How can a Linux beginner install that code in Elementary OS? Direct access to the directory /lib/firmware is blocked.

Likely, you mean, you'll need root access as that folder is protected. Read sudo_root manpage to learn more about how to gain root access to move files into protected folders.

```
   By  default, the password for the user "root" (the system administrator) is locked. 
   This means you cannot login as root or use su. Instead, the installer will set up sudo 
   to allow the user that is created during install to run all administrative commands.

   This means that in the terminal you can use sudo for commands that require root 
   privileges. All programs in the menu will use a graphical sudo to prompt for a 
   password. When sudo asks for a password, it needs your  password,  this means that a 
   root password is not needed.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo cp /home/user/Downloads/iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode /lib/firmware/ && sudo cp /home/user/Downloads/iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode /lib/firmware/
```